# Download chocolatey packages with dependencies but install it later

Tags: download, azure-devops, dependencies, chocolatey

I´ve got a question about the package installation manager 'chocolatey'. The use case is that I want to download packages from a feed (hosted on azure devOps) including dependencies and save them somewhere on my computer. So I could install these packages later from a local source.

Is it possible to do so? If yes how can I do this

Thanks for your effort! For Further questions don't hesitate to comment my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps 1:
Download artifact from the Azure DevOps feed and save it on the computer.

**1**. Open power shell and login DevOps via the code az login

**2**. Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#download-a-universal-package) and run the code to download the artifact from the Azure DevOps feed.

```
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/{org} --feed feed name --name package name --version verion ID --path .
```

Step 2:
In this step, you can call [chocolatey-install-package](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package) command to achieve installing local package. Just run this script in command line task.